# Trouble reinstalling Gem after power failure

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Yesterday I tried to install [`Jeweler`](http://github.com/technicalpickles/jeweler) via Rubygems, however somewhere in the middle of the process I had a power failure, resulting in my computer turning off in the middle of the installation process.

Once I got it back up, I tried to reinstall [`Jeweler`](http://github.com/technicalpickles/jeweler), however resulting in an error I've had trouble decoding.

[alt text http://img63.imageshack.us/img63/438/shot20100415145730.png](http://img63.imageshack.us/img63/438/shot20100415145730.png)

Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this problem? (I tried `uninstall`, `cleanup` and `check`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve it, by uninstalling all dependencies possible via Ruby Gems, and the rest manually by deleting the files (including Jeweler itself).